# "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS" Error

Tags: mysql, sql

---

I am trying to get following query working:

I wrote this Stored Procedure:

```
IF (@Mode='CurrentRootList') 
BEGIN
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
        ORDER BY emp1.EmployeeName ASC
  )AS RowNumber 
  ,emp1.empid 
  ,emp1.EmployeeName
  ,(SELECT * FROM [Mobile_Locations] mloc where emp1.MobileID=mloc.MobileID AND mloc.LocationTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, mloc.LocationTime , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) as LocationTime
  ,emp1.ArrivalTime
  ,emp1.DeviceStatus      
 INTO #CurrentDateRootList
  FROM [EMP_Locations] emp1 join [Root] root1 ON emp1.EmployeeName = root1.EmployeeName  where (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN root1.StartDate AND root1.EndDate)


  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #CurrentDateRootList

  SELECT * FROM #CurrentDateRootList
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #CurrentDateRootList
END
```

---

How to solve this error .
Please help me.

Comment: You have this tagged MySQL, and yet it looks an awful lot like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery that populates the LocationTime probably returns more than one row. You should add a LIMIT 1 for that subquery.

EDIT: and also make sure that subquery returns only one column (noticed the * ..).

Comment: where i want to put LIMIT 1 in this query ??

Comment: @Aks, the last clause of the subquery should be " LIMIT 1 ". So that means (select ... from ... where ... LIMIT 1). Please consider also replacing the "*" with a single column in the subquery.